# In a damped oscillation with damping force $F=-bu$ at which position does the maximum velocity occur?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, oscillators

In a SHO we know that V will become a maximum in the equilibrium position with V= Aω. Does the same apply to a damped oscillation with the damping force being F=-bu or is the position somewhere else?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Is V=u?

Answer (score 0):

The position of maximum speed precedes the equilibrium position.

Perhaps the easiest way to see this is to consider the net force at the equilibrium position, as long as the mass is still moving. The restoring force is zero, but the damping is still retarding motion. Therefore, the speed had to have been higher earlier.

The extreme example can be seen with overdamped systems, which never reach the equilibrium position and whose speed monotonically decreases from the moment they're released.

[image]

(from the [Wikipedia article on damping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping))

Answer (score 0):

starting with the equation of motion

$$\ddot x+\frac bm\dot x+\frac cm=0$$

you obtain the solution $~x(t)~$ with  $~(x(0)=0~,\dot x(0)=v_0)~$

$$x(t)=\rm e^{-\beta\,t}\,\frac{v_0}{\omega_b}\sin(\omega_b\,t)$$

where $~\beta=\frac{b}{2m}~,\omega_b^2=\frac cm-\left(\frac{b}{2\,m}\right)^2~$

the velocity $~v(t)~$ is $~\dot x(t)~$
solve $~v(t)=0~$ for t and substitute to the solution  $~x(t)~$ you obtain for the undamped case $~b=0$
$$x_{m1}=\frac{v_0}{\omega}\quad,\omega^2=\frac cm$$

and for the damped case

$$x_{m2}=\frac{v_0}{\omega}\,{{\rm e}^{-b\arccos \left( \frac 12\,{\frac {b}{\omega\,m}} \right) {\frac 
{1}{\sqrt {4\,{\omega}^{2}{m}^{2}-{b}^{2}}}}}}
$$

from here

$$x_{m2}\, <\, x_{m1}$$